# How to connect to a |Database from SQL Script, in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, toad

Hi i am trying to connect to a DB using a connection string mentioned in a Script file.. in SQL developer.

I am using the below format

Connect USERNAME/PASSWORD@HOSTNAME:PORT/Service_name..

But its not working same pattern works in TOAD, i want to do this via a connection string from script file.